# How to comb wavy beard from looking stray

Tags: personal-care, hair

I got wavy hair and I love growing beard but I had to cut it short because I cannot trim at home as I have a vision problem so it is after every month along with hair cut. But during that time when it grows, it feel more stray hair and I look ugly. Same can be said with head hair as they start becoming wavy (that is another story).

How can I make my beard hair look decent and not flying/stray when I look down or everyday office.

Comment: Have you tried oils such as avocado or olive oil? Pour oil in your palm and gently go down the length of your beard. If your hair is dry it may take some time for it to be hydrated. Not sure if you are aware of this but they sell beard conditioners as well for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

A beard is "just hair", but thicker and stronger. You can use any hair product on your beard as well, but it might not work quite as well.

- Oils: they nurture the hairs and keep them smooth. There are special beard oils that can nurture or soothe the skin as well. Put 1 - 2 drops onto your palm, then rub it through your beard.
- Conditioner: works much like oil, but doesn't give your beard the wet look. Rub some of it into your beard while showering, wait a minute, then rinse it out.
- Comb your beard: especially after a shower, you can tell the individual hairs of your beard how to fall by combing them. For a better result, you can blow dry your beard while combing it or brushing it with a big round brush (that should smooth out some of your curls). If you don't want to comb/brush, you should at least dry the beard by moving the towel from your cheeks towards your chin and down your beard instead of rubbing it chaotically through your beard.
- Hair mousse: This works like hair gel, but is applied to wet hair, usually before blow drying. Put a small dallop on a comb and comb it through your moist beard, then form the beard into the shape you want. Don't forget to rinse the residue from your comb.

Comment: when u say just hair, why there are "beard shampoo" and "shampoo"? Can one use hair wax or cream on beard and wash it from same shampoo as head?

Comment: @Nofel I honestly don't know how "beard shampoo" and "head shampoo" differ, it's probably just marketing. Beard hairs are thicker and stiffer than the hairs on your head, so you might need a stronger hair wax, but any normal shampoo should be able to clean your beard just as well. If your skin feels itchy or dry, you can use "sensitive" shampoo instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use hard hair wax and comb it daily and clean beard 3 times a week and apply oil 2-3 times of week depend on the hair density.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SE. I use oil daily as my hair are too wavy. what annoy me most is stray hair when I look down I can see them.

Comment: Use Hard wax it helps me to keep the beard straighten, but you have to do it daily after 20 days you see the result.

Comment: What sort of result and any good brand do u recommend?

Comment: Actually I am using the Indian brand but you can use the wax which contains following things. Microcrystalline wax, Copernicia cerifera(carnauba) Wax, Mineral oil, Dimethicone, Polyethylene, Glyceryl stearate, Polysorbate 60, Stearic Acid, Cetyl Ethylhexanoate, Myristyl alcohol, Phenoxyethanol, Potassium Hydroxide..